# Proof Ideas - Strong Induction, Pascal's Triangle and Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: reference-request, induction, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

I'm looking for attributes/characteristics/properties to prove about Pascal's Triangle or the Fibonacci numbers. Preferably something that requires a strong induction proof that is on the same level as proving things such as the sum of the elements in the nth row of Pascal's triangle is $2^n$. Simple induction proof ideas are also fine.

Comment: How about Pascal's triangle *and* the Fibonacci numbers? Try proving that $F_{n+1} = \sum_{k \ge 0} {n-k \choose k}$.

Comment: The known properties of Pascal's triangle, and of the Fibonacci sequence, that can be proved by induction, can each  fill a library.